# find if a given timestamp belongs to set A or set B

Tags: python, timestamp

I want to 'classify' timestamps to either A or B, where A and B are sets of timeframes. More specifically, I have a few dates in the following format '2014-11-23T12:00:00.000+04:00'. What I would like to do is to find whether each of them 'belongs' either to set [between 11 and 16 on Monday or 11 and 16 Tuesday] or to set [between 11 Saturday to 16 on Sunday] or to non of these sets. Any ideas how to implement this in Python?

**EDIT:**

The following code works fine for the provided date string, however, it is not complied with my date string as I use a slightly different format (i.e. '2014-11-23T12:00:00.000+04:00')

```
from datetime import datetime
new_time = datetime.strptime('2012-03-01T10:00:00Z','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
print(new_time)
```

Comment: You can use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module to convert your timestamps to `datetime` objects. Then you can do [greater than and less than](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142364/how-to-compare-two-dates) comparisons between timestamps, to see if it is in a certain range.

Comment: I have updated my question based on my findings. Can you please have a look?

Comment: You may want to check out the [arrow](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/) library for manipulating datetimes.

Comment: @WayneWerner seems nice. It can read the provided date string very easily. However, it doesn't seem to support string day formats such as 'Sat', 'Sun' and so on. Any ideas?

Comment: Write a simple dictionary, e.g. `DAYS_OF_WEEK = {'Thurs': 3, ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Python has nice rich comparisons. Specifically, you can write:

```
if low < myval < high:
    print("{} is between {} and {}".format(myval, low, high))
```

And it works exactly as you expect.

If you run `dir(new_time)` you'll find a list of interesting looking properties, like `weekday`, and `hour`. So you could do something like

```
THURSDAY = 3

if new_time.weekday == THURSDAY and low_time < new_time.hour < high_time:
    print("{} is on Thursday between {} and {}".format(new_time,
                                                       low_time,
                                                       high_time))
```

You also might want to make sure that `.minute`/`.second`/`.microsecond` aren't > 0. Of course if it's a *specific* Monday or Friday you're looking for, you could easily create your times like so:

```
monday_at_1100 = datetime(2014, 12, 8, 11)
monday_at_1600 = datetime(2014, 12, 8, 16)

if monday_at_1100 < new_time < monday_at_1600:
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

Two general approaches that scale:

**Reduce the precision** of your data.

Map timetstamp 12:13:14 to 12:*****, then you can have a comprehensive set of timestamp in native Python set:

```
"12:*****" in set(["12:*****", "17:*****"])
True
```

**Use binary tree** or heap or skip list or similar hierarchical data structure

```
        (12:00, 17:59)
          /       \
(12:00, 12:59)  (17:00, 17:59)
```