# building and comparing times

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

1. I want to create time that is based on `Year-Month-day`. Lets call it `a_date`.
2. I want to take current time with for example `datetime.now()` and format it to same format above. Lets call it `b_date`.
3. I want to tell if `b_date <= a_date`.

How do I do that? I tried several things with `time.mktime()` and `strftime`, but I'm little confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142364/how-to-compare-two-dates)

Comment: Basically if both a_date and b_date are strings, then if b_date is older date then a_date, string comparison should give you direct answer because of the YYYY-MM-DD format!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import datetime

# year, month, day
a_date = datetime.date(2014, 11, 1)
b_date = datetime.date.today()

print(b_date)          # 2016-01-13
print(a_date < b_date) # true
```

Comment: But when yeilding datetime.now(), I get more extended format, with hours minutes seconds

Comment: @JavaSa Use `datetime.date.today()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
def validitycheck():
    from datetime import datetime
    valid = datetime(2016, 1, 23)
    oldValid = datetime(2016, 1, 7)
    present = datetime.now()

    if not valid >= present or present <= oldValid:
        appValid = False
    else:
        appValid = True
    return appValid 
print validitycheck()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import datetime, calendar

def getTimestamp(a):
    return calendar.timegm(a.timetuple())

a_date = datetime.datetime(year, month, day)
b_date = datetime.datetime.now()
if getTimestamp(a_date) <= getTimestamp(b_date):
    # a_date <= b_date
```

---

*References:*
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html
https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm