# Epoch Time and Time Zones

Tags: python, date, time, epoch

Here's my problem, I have 2 times I'm feeding into Python, one in EST and other in GMT. I need to convert both to epoch and compare them. From what it's looking like when I convert the EST to epoch, it's should convert to the exact equivalent of GMT I thought. It doesn't look like it is:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt,datetime,timedelta
import time

# EST
date_time = '09.03.1999' + " " + "08:44:17"
pattern = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'
epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date_time, pattern)))
print epoch

# GMT
date_time2 = '09.03.1999' + " " + "13:44:17.000000"
pattern2 = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'
epoch2 = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date_time2, pattern2)))
print epoch2
```

Comment: You don't need ton convert them to epoch to compare them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142364/how-to-compare-two-dates
Otherwise, you may find this resource instructive: http://www.idiotinside.com/2015/03/14/working-with-date-and-time-python-892/

Comment: I should clarify that I figured epoch conversion would be easier since I do this comparison later on: `if (epoch - 120) < epoch2 and epoch2 < (epoch + 120)`

Comment: I also will be doing filters with this time in Wireshark, which is easy to do with epoch

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you're confusing what epoch means here.
Epoch is a representation of time which counts the numbers of seconds from 1970/01/01 00:00:00 to a given a date.

Epoch conversion doesn't care about timezones and you can actually have negative epoch times with timezone conversion (play around at http://www.epochconverter.com/).

A real example: I live in Japan, so local time epoch 0 for me is actually -32400 in GMT epoch.

What you need to do is do something like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/python-convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime) to first convert between timezones and then do the date to epoch conversion.

Here's some code from the accepted answer:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

from_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')
to_zone = tz.gettz('America/New_York')

utc = datetime.strptime('2011-01-21 02:37:21', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# Tell the datetime object that it's in UTC time zone since 
# datetime objects are 'naive' by default
utc = utc.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)

# Convert time zone
central = utc.astimezone(to_zone)
```

Comment: Once I get the times the same, can I use the same convention to convert to epoch: `pattern = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'
epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(gmt, pattern)))
print epoch`

Comment: Nice snippet, however last line: `central = ...` is odd since `'America/New_York'` is Eastern Time Zone in US.  Central is for Chicago, and those longitudes in the midwest