# Compare two date by month & date Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, date

I have two columns of dates need to be compared, date1 is a list of certain dates, date2 is random date (dob). I need to compare month and day by some conditon to make a flag. sample like:

```
df_sample = DataFrame({'date1':('2015-01-15','2015-01-15','2015-03-15','2015-04-15','2015-05-15'),
                       'dob':('1999-01-25','1987-12-12','1965-03-02','2000-08-02','1992-05-15')}
```

I create a function based on condition below

```
def eligible(date1,dob):
  if date1.month - dob.month==0 and date1.day <= dob.day:
    return 'Y'
  elif date1.month - dob.month==1 and date1.day > dob.day:
    return 'Y'
  else:
    return 'N'
```

I want to apply this function to orginal df which has more than 5M rows, hence for loop is not efficiency, is there any way to achieve this?

Datatype is *date*, not *datetime*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142364/how-to-compare-two-dates

Comment: Hey, I dont consider year, I just need to compare month and day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with conditions chained by `|` (`or`):

```
df_sample['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sample['date1'])
df_sample['dob'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sample['dob'])

months_diff = df_sample.date1.dt.month  - df_sample.dob.dt.month
days_date1 = df_sample.date1.dt.day
days_dob = df_sample.dob.dt.day

m1 = (months_diff==0) & (days_date1 <= days_dob)
m2 = (months_diff==1) & (days_date1 > days_dob)

df_sample['out'] = np.where(m1 | m2 ,'Y','N')
print (df_sample)
       date1        dob out
0 2015-01-15 1999-01-25   Y
1 2015-01-15 1987-12-12   N
2 2015-03-15 1965-03-02   N
3 2015-04-15 2000-08-02   N
4 2015-05-15 1992-05-15   Y
```

Comment: Thanks, if I prefer date datatype, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. but pandas native type is datetime, so date can be slowier and not possible use `dt.*` functions. But if need date as last step use `df_sample['date1'] = df_sample['date1'].dt.date`

Answer (score 0):

Using `datetime` is certainly beneficial:

```
df_sample['dob'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sample['dob'])
df_sample['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sample['date1'])
```

Once you have it, your formula can be literally applied to all rows:

```
df_sample['eligible'] = 
              (  (df_sample.date1.dt.month == df_sample.dob.dt.month)\
               & (df_sample.date1.dt.day <= df_sample.dob.dt.day)) |\
              (  (df_sample.date1.dt.month - df_sample.dob.dt.month == 1)\
               & (df_sample.date1.dt.day > df_sample.dob.dt.day))
```

The result is boolean (`True`/`False`), but you can easily convert it to "Y"/"N", if you want.