# Querying data between set times

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I am trying to return current date data between set times. The query below is returning all data for today. The tricky bit that I am finding to do is to only return the data between midnight and 1pm for today.

How can I attempt this? FYI – the doctype ‘VT’ has value of 2017-10-13 04:35:02.33
Not sure if that might help

```
POST _search
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "VT": {
                "gte": "now/d" 
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess you are using python, so you can handle the gte and lte in your python code and just pass it to the query.

Comment: @hatim, i am using python. could you take a look at my other post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712620/how-to-use-date-range-in-python-to-pull-query-data-using-current-date

and see if you can help on that?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
POST _search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "VT": {
                        "gte": "now/d" 
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "range": {
                    "VT": {
                        "gte": "00:00:00",
                        "lte": "13:00:00",
                        "format": "H:m:s"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i got a error saying -    duplicate key "range" -  "type": "parsing_exception",
      "reason": "[range] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",

Comment: still not work. i guess this is not doable. been stuck on it for days now

Answer (score 0):

Can this help you?

```
POST _search
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "VT": {
                "gte": "now/d",
                "lt": "now/d+13h"
            }
        }
    }

}
```