# Extracted from the array to 2007-1-1 to 2007-12-31 with Python?

Tags: python, arrays, extract

Look at the Python code：

```
base = ['2018-1-9', '2017-1-1', '2017-4-10', '2015-2-15', '2017-12-31', '2018-1-8', '2017-12-31', '2017-4-10', '2017-3-16']
for item in base:
    if item <= '2017-12-31':
        print(item)
```

This results in

```
2017-1-1
2015-2-15
2017-12-31
2017-12-31
```

I want to print all the dates in 2017:

```
2017-1-1
2017-4-10
2017-12-31
2017-12-31
2017-4-10
2017-3-16
```

What needs to be changed in my code?

Comment: if you want to compare dates as strings, make sure they are built as YYYY-MM-DD (es. base = ['2018-01-09', '2017-01-01', '2017-04-10', '2015-02-15', '2017-12-31', '2018-01-08', '2017-12-31', '2017-04-10', '2017-03-16')]

Comment: You should also test item >= "2017-01-01"

Comment: FYI It better practice to also try to understand the answers. this how you can develop your coding skills (i.e. read the documentation attached etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should turn the given strings to a date object and check what ever you like on the object.

I would suggest you to use the library datetime
you can read about  [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) and you can some [examples](http://strftime.org/).

For your code it would like:

```
base = ['2018-1-9', '2017-1-1', '2017-4-10', '2015-2-15', '2017-12-31', '2018-1-8', '2017-12-31', '2017-4-10',
        '2017-3-16']
max_date = datetime.strptime('2017-12-31', '%Y-%m-%d')
min_date = datetime.strptime('2017-1-1', '%Y-%m-%d')
for item in base:
    d = datetime.strptime(item, '%Y-%m-%d')
    if d <= max_date and d >= min_date:
        print(item)
```

the result is:

```
2017-1-1
2017-4-10
2017-12-31
2017-12-31
2017-4-10
2017-3-16
```

Comment: This is not 2015-2-15.Can you do the result I want? Thank you!

Comment: what do you want? according the code you wants all the dates before 2018.
you want also to ass a condition that it would be after 1.1.2017?

Comment: from 2007-1-1 to 2007-12-31 is just fine.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing objects of type `string` instead of `date`. You can look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142364/how-to-compare-two-dates) to learn how to compare dates. And [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime) to check how to create date/datetime object based on the string.

Please consider the code below:

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Nov 23 2017, 15:37:09) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170406] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> date1 = "2018-1-9"
>>> date2 = "2017-1-1"
>>> # converting strings into dates
>>> date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
>>> date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date2, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
>>> date1 <= date2
False
>>> date2 <= date1
True
```

First, you need to convert your `string` into `date` object using [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) library. You need to provide date format in order to convert it properly (part `%Y-%m-%d` from code example). After you have your date object you can use comparing operators.