# How to check if a date is expired but also make sure that it is no more than a year from today's date

Tags: python, date, time, compare

I have tried to use the datetime code but i really don't understand it very much. I have managed to allow the user to input a date but i am not quite sure how to compare the dates. Here is what i have so far.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

import re

validDate = False
while not validDate:
    cdate = input("please enter your card expiration date: ")

    if (re.match("^([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})$", cdate)):
        print("Valid")
        validDate = True
    else:
        print("Error. Enter date in format dd/mm/yyyy")
```

I really have no clue how to compare the two please help me. if you have any suggestions for code that might be on this site please tell me. In the meantime i will keep trying to research.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142364/how-to-compare-two-dates)

Comment: i have looked at how to compare two dates and tried the code but it has not worked for me,

Comment: Please update your question with the code you tried then. In your sample code there is no comparison yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this one :

```
 from datetime import datetime, date
 datet = input("please enter your card expiration date: ")

 ExpirationDate = datetime.strptime(datet,"%Y-%m-%d").date()
 now = date.today()
 if ExpirationDate < now:
      print("expired")
```

for your second condition you can use `ExpirationDate.year` for the year of entered date and `now.year` for current year. With that you can write condition according to your need .

```
 if ExpirationDate.year > now.year+1:
      print("date not accepted")
 elif ExpirationDate < now :
      print("expired")
 else :
      print("valid ")
```

remaining all code is same

**UPDATE :**

```
from datetime import datetime, date

while True:
    datet = input("please enter your card expiration date: ")
    ExpirationDate = datetime.strptime(datet, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    now = date.today()
    if ExpirationDate.year > now.year + 1:
         print("date not accepted")
         continue
    elif ExpirationDate < now:
         print("expired")
         continue
    else:
         print("valid ")
         break
```

it will again ask to enter date if `date not accpted` or `expired`

Comment: I tired but every time i enter a date it doesn't do anything. it just moves on to the next part of the code

Comment: Is this what you mean by the format of the input?  2016-06-12

Comment: So when you want to print expire ? when the entering date is less than today or higher than today ?

Comment: when it is less than today. but also when it is more than a year in the future from today

Comment: Thank you it works now if i input a date that is less than today. how would i be able to do the second part of the code and not allow the user to input a date further than a year in the future.

Comment: Can you explain with some sample data and o/p, i can surely help you with that .

Comment: for example if the date entered is 2010-01-01 then it should be wrong

Comment: the current code is working for the same right ? about second condition.

Comment: @dariusDEAnzo check the updated answer . Is that you want to do in your second condition ?

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much for your time and skill. If i could ask one more thing, how do i make it so that it restarts the code if its wrong?

Comment: @dariusDEAnzo wrong means which condition, expired or date not accepted ?

Comment: sorry i wasn't on for a while i had a problem. yes by wrong i mean expired. thank you.

Comment: yes the code is now perfect. thank you so much for everything. you have been very patient and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should use [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#module-calendar).