# How to calculate number of days between two days in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the number of days b/w two given days.The problem that I am facing is when the first day comes late as compared to the second day.
Example-If the first day is Saturday and the second one is Monday so the number of days that exists b/w them should be 3 but my code fails to do this.

```
a="saturday monday 1 2"
f=a.split(" ")
l=["monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday","sunday"]
g=abs(l.index(f[0])-l.index(f[1]))+1
print(g)
```

Comment: Use modulus to wrap the negative index difference around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142364/how-to-compare-two-dates)

Comment: Days between Saturday and Monday will be `1` right, which is `Sunday`

Comment: I think there should be 2 days from Saturday to Monday, if from Saturday and Saturday there are zero

Answer (score 2):

Subtract indexes for both days, and take a modulo 7. Putting this in a function, we have

```
def day_diff(a, b):
    l = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]

    return (l.index(b) - l.index(a))%7

print(day_diff('saturday', 'monday'))
#2
print(day_diff('monday', 'saturday'))
#5
print(day_diff('monday', 'monday'))
#0
print(day_diff('monday', 'sunday'))
#6
```

Answer (score 1):

This will handle your problem:

```
a="saturday monday 1 2"
#a= "monday tuesday"
f=a.split(" ")
l=["monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday","sunday"]
sym = (l.index(f[0])-l.index(f[1]))
if sym <= 0:
    g=abs(sym)+1
else:
    new_sym = 7 - sym
    g=abs(new_sym)+1
```