# How to compare dates in python and find the greater one

Tags: python, date, date-comparison

I want to compare 2 date and predict a label true if date 1 greater than date 2 and predict false date 1 less than date 2.
I have trained the model but model is predicting wrong for near by dates that is if  `13-01-2020` and `14-01-2020` is given it will predict true but the right answer is false.

Comment: please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142364/how-to-compare-two-dates

Comment: In what sense predict? To me prediction is saying that something will happen *before* it happens.

Comment: if date 1 greater than date 2 predict a label true else false that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import datetime
StartDate = "13-01-2020"
EndDate = "14-01-2020"
res = datetime.datetime.strptime(StartDate, '%d-%m-%Y')
res2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(EndDate, '%d-%m-%Y')
if res>res2:
    print(StartDate)
elif res<res2:
    print(EndDate)
```

Convert string into datetime format and then compare it.