# how to compare date from get request to date.now?

Tags: python

```
for count in json_data['data']:
    exp = str(count['expires_on'])
    print(exp)
```

I have this piece of code that print me exp(date in format 2022-05-11). I need to create an `if` condition that compares these dates from get request with current date -30 days. I'm new in Python and try many ways, may anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142364/how-to-compare-two-dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

exp = "2020-08-31"

if (datetime.strptime(exp, "%Y-%m-%d") - timedelta(days=30)).date() == datetime.now().date():
    print("Yes")
```