# select specific period in python

Tags: python

I have a dataset containing the following column:

```
date<BR>
2016-09-01<BR>
2016-10-05<BR>
2015-02-07<BR>
2017-02-18<BR>
2019-11-27<BR>
2020-01-24<BR>
2010-09-14<BR>
```

I want to select the rows from 1-10-2016 till now, and I have the following script:

```
df_selection=df[(df['date'] >= 2016-10-1)]<BR>
df_selection
```

But I get the following error with this script:
Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and int

How can I make a correct selection?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you literally use this? `df_selection=df[(df['date'] >= 2016-10-1)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142364/how-to-compare-two-dates)

Comment: yes, so what is wrong then?

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because `2016-10-1` **is not a date**, it's a subtraction of integers, giving an integer. Use an actual date `datetime.date(2016, 10, 1)`

If you get your dates from strings, you can use `datetime.strptime` to convert it to an actual date object.

Comment: I don't know how to use this in my script. My column ['date'] is already a dtype: datetime64[ns]

Comment: your column is, but `2016-10-1` is not. write it as a `datetime.date` object

Comment: Sorry, I am a slow learner and I just don't know how to use it in a script. How do I change the column 'date' into a workable column?

Comment: the column is okay already, the problem is `2016-10-1`, use `datetime.date(2016, 10, 1)` instead.