# Simple python string opertation

Tags: python, string, datetime

I have a string

```
url = 'https://www.xyz/2020-12-22'
```

I want to change this url variable to  'https://www.xyz/2020-12-21' (Means subtaction one from only date value). How can I do that ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Learn python strings.

Comment: @TomServo kindly give me a possible solution, I have to loop thousands of time

Comment: @backloggiash well this is basic python string formatting, if You know loops You should also know how to format strings, I suggest You look into [`f strings`](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Comment: Your question is unclear and shows lack of research effort.  You've shown no attempt to solve the problem.  If you want to modify a string like that URL, then learn to modify strings in python.

Comment: I solved using  `'-'.join(url.split('-')[:-1]  +   [str(int(url.split('-')[-1]) -1 )] )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the datetime module

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

url = 'https://www.xyz/2020-12-22'

#take slice of url that represents the date
dateString = url[-10:]

#convert string to date object
d = date.fromisoformat(dateString)

#subtract 1 day
url = 'https://www.xyz/' + str(d - timedelta(days=1))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a regular expression to catch the date inside the string. Convert it to datetime, then [subtract a day using `datetime.timedelta()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142364/how-to-compare-two-dates). Use an f-string to join the new date and the url.

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
import re

url = 'https://www.xyz/2020-12-22'
date = re.findall(r"[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}", url)
date = datetime.strptime(date[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
date = date - timedelta(1)
date = date.date()
print(date)
print(f'https://www.xyz/{date}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey I made a little solution I know it's not the best but maybe it helps you

```
url = 'https://www.xyz/2020-12-22'
date = url.split("-")
result = int(date[2]) -1
new_url = date[0] + "-" + date[1] + "-" + str(result)
print(new_url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple one-liner solution.  It assumes that your date is greater that 01.

```
new_url = url[:-2] + str(int(url[-2:])-1)
```

Comment: I already mentioned that this simple solution assumes that the date is greater than 01.  Otherwise, you can resort to the datetime solution.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've missed that part (I've just removed the comment).

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

url = 'https://www.xyz/2020-12-22'
   
url_parts = url.rsplit('/', 1)
url = url_parts[0] + (datetime.fromisoformat(url_parts[1]) + timedelta(days=1)).strftime("/%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using:

```
'-'.join(url.split('-')[:-1] + [str(int(url.split('-')[-1]) -1 )] )
```

Comment: This doesn't work if it is the first of the month. See if my answer works better for you.