# Converting a string into a date within a for loop

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to compare a date in a CSV file to days date - If todays date is bigger then the output will be no.

I am trying to figure out if the expiry date of a card is past todays date:

```
#input number you want to search
number = input('Enter the card number\n')
#read csv, and split on "," the line
   csv_file = csv.reader(open('carddetails.csv', "r"), delimiter=",")
#loop through the csv list
   for row in csv_file:
    #if current rows 2nd value is equal to input, print that row
      if number == row[1]:
         valid_to_date = row[3]
         if valid_to_date>todays_Date:
                     
            print("nop")
         else:
            print("yep")
```

I have declared `todays_Date` as a global variable else where.

It works in regards to giving me the date but it tells me that I cannot compare str and date.time.
I haven't done much with datetime so looking how to convert `valid_to_date` to a date.time to be able to compare them.

Comment: It seems your question would be the same if no loop was involved, wouldn't it?

Comment: Well the fact is I pull the data from the row inside the loop. But I guess it would be, yes.  I was just told before to give the whole story and any code I have written, and this is it.

Comment: You can use strptime on your str.

Comment: You can use the same ideas given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142364/how-to-compare-two-dates

Comment: If the date in the CSV (row[3]) and *todays_Date* are both in the YYYMMDD format, then they can be compared lexicographically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're need to convert your string date to a datetime object with datetime.strptime

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

```
# if your date in your csv is in format YYYYmmddTHHMMSS (year-month-day:hour-min-sec then
from datetime import datetime
valid_datetime = datetime.strptime(valid_to_date, "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")

# now you can compare the datetimes
if valid_datetime > todays_date:
    valid = "NO"
```